# Dynamic Healthbars - Dynamic Observables and Dependencies

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

This question will be a little specific, so feel free to answer in more broad terms, or point me in the right direction.

I have picked up Knockout.js a few days ago because it solves a problem that I had beforehand in my application, though that being said, being so new to a library tends to make more problems...

I'm trying to make a simple PC (Playable Character) manager for a GM (Game Master) application. I load all the PC information from a json object array(later to be from a db), and put them in a Bootstrap Tab Panel for easy maintenance.

The first thing I would like to create is a health bar for each player with a control to the side for adding and subtracting hp, and a X/Y simple text view. Each of these components should be independent from components for another player and should all update dynamically upon the value in the input box being submitted.

The problem that I'm having is thinking in terms of knockout rather than in terms of simple javascript. I will explain this later.

Here is my code:

~ JSON array with data:

```
    var initialData = [
    {
        id: 0,
        pcName: "Player 1",
        hp: 12,
        curHp: 12,
        name: "Dudebro One",
        playerClass: "Ranger",
        level: 1,
        background: "",
        race: "Elf - Wood",
        Alignment: "",
        exp: 700,
        inspiration: 0,
        proficiencyBonus: 0
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        pcName: "Player 2",
        hp: 10,
        curHp: 10,
        name: "Brodude Two",
        playerClass: "Fighter",
        level: 1,
        background: "Soldier",
        race: "Gnome",
        Alignment: "",
        exp: 700,
        inspiration: 0,
        proficiencyBonus: 0
    }
];
```

(Note: the data is incomplete for readability purposes. Also assume `n` number of players, not 2)

~ the Knockout code (FAR from complete):

```
var PCModel = function (pcs) {
    var self = this;

    var currentHp = ko.observable(10);
    var maximumHp = ko.observable(10);

    self.pcsList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(pcs, function (pc) {
        return {
            id: pc.id, pcName: pc.pcName, hp: pc.hp, curHp: pc.curHp, name: pc.name, playerClass: pc.playerClass, level: pc.level, background: pc.background, race: pc.race, Alignment: pc.Alignment, exp: pc.exp,
            inspiration: pc.inspiration, proficiencyBonus: pc.proficiencyBonus
        };
    }));

    //TODO: REMOVE (Note: Here just for testing).
    self.myFunction= function(pc){
        currentHp--;
    };

    self.getHpPercentage = function (pc) {
        var hpRound = Math.round((pc.curHp / pc.hp) * 100);
        return hpRound + "%"
    }

    self.hpClass = function (pc) {
        var hp = currentHp() / maximumHp() * 100;
        if (hp >= 70) {
            return 'progress-bar-success';
        } else if (hp < 70 && hp >= 30) {
            return 'progress-bar-warning';
        } else if (hp < 30) {
            return 'progress-bar-danger';
        }
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new PCModel(initialData));
```

Now let me explain myself. I know that for things to update dynamically, I either need to define observables or manually subscribe things. I decided to go the observable route. My problem here is that `var maximumHp = ko.observable(10);`, for example, does not make sense in my case, since I have all the data I need in a json array. Furthermore, `maximumHp` needs to be so for the CURRENT object being viewed/worked on. I have no idea how to define that...

~My html code with binding (again, nowhere close to complete):

```
<div style="float:right; margin-top:25px; width: 65vw;">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: pcsList">

        <li data-bind="css: {active: $index() == 0 }" >
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#tab' + id}, text: pcName" data-toggle="tab"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container-border-cup">
        <div class="tab-content " data-bind="foreach: pcsList">

            <div class="tab-pane tabbed-content-style" data-bind="attr: {id: 'tab' + id}, css: {active: $index() == 0 }">
                <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>

                <div style="float:left; font-size:15pt; font-weight:500; line-height:35px; padding-right:20px; min-width:100px;">
                    <span data-bind="text: curHp"></span>/<span data-bind="text: hp"></span>
                </div>

                <button data-bind="click: $root.myFunction">
                    Click me
                </button>

                <div class="progress" style="width: 50%; height: 35px; float:left">
                    <div class="progress-bar" style="float:left;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" data-bind="text: $root.getHpPercentage($data), attr:{class: 'progress-bar ' + $root.hpClass($data)}, style:{width: $root.getHpPercentage($data)}"></div>
                </div>


                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:20px">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnToggleHP" value="-" style="width: 35px; font-weight:900;" />
                    </span>
                    <input id="inModHP" style="width:70px" type="text" class="form-control" value="0">
                    <span class="input-group-btn" style="float:left">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnGoHP" value="Go" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

All of the preceding code gives off the following effect:
[image]

(Don't worry about the ulgy button, that's the one that's just for testing). Ideally, in the end, the user would be able to click the red minus button, and toggle it between that and a green plus to identify adding or subtracting from the health pool. Clicking the Go button should cascade update everything.

While I could probably hack together something that works in the end, I'd like to learn some good practices along the way.

Thanks for reading through my novel of a question, and thank's even more if you're willing to drop an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the behavior you're implementing is related to each player, you should put the logic in a `PlayerViewModel` and have one model for each player. You can keep track of the collection of models in another viewmodel. Let's call it `App`.

In `App`, we only do *one* thing:

1. Take the json array and create a *new* `PlayerViewModel` for each object that's in it.

When we create a `new Player`, we do several things:

1. First, we copy all the static json properties to our new player instance. You can do this manually, like you already did in your code, or you can do it automatically, like I did with `Object.assign`.
2. Then, we override some properties to use `ko.observable`s. *Every property you want to be able to change in the UI, has to be an observable*. So, if you would want to be able to change a name, you'll have to add that as an observable as well.
3. Now we can add our own observable and computed values as well. For example: if the player can change `curHp`, we can automatically compute an HP percentage.
4. Finally, every `Player` gets a set of functions via the `Player.prototype`. E.g.: there's a function that takes the value in an `input` field and adds it to the `curHp`.

Now, because all info and logic is inside the `Player` model, you can easily data-bind without having to pass along references to players, and without having to use `$parent` or `$root`.

```js
var Player = function(playerData) {
  // Make a copy of all properties to the new player
  // These are static properties, suitably for one-way
  // data-binding.
  Object.assign(this, playerData);
  
  // Create observables for two-way properties
  // (properties you want to change via the UI)
  this.curHp = ko.observable(playerData.curHp);
  this.subtractValue = ko.observable(0);
  
  // Create computed values for the UI
  this.hpPercentage = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return (this.curHp() / playerData.hp * 100).toFixed(1);
  }, this);
  
  this.healthWarning = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var hpPerc = this.hpPercentage();
    if (hpPerc === 0) return "Dead";
    if (hpPerc < 30) return "Watch out";
    if (hpPerc < 70) return "Steady";
    return "OK";
  }, this);
};

// Add functions
Player.prototype.addHp = function() {
  var val = parseFloat(this.subtractValue());
  var newHP = Math.min(
    Math.max(this.curHp() + val, 0), this.hp);
  
  this.curHp(newHP);
};

// A helper constructor
Player.create = function(playerJson) {
  return new Player(playerJson);
};

var App = function(jsonData) {
  this.players = jsonData.map(Player.create);
};


var initialData=[{id:0,pcName:"Player 1",hp:12,curHp:4,name:"Dudebro One",playerClass:"Ranger",level:1,background:"",race:"Elf - Wood",Alignment:"",exp:700,inspiration:0,proficiencyBonus:0},{id:1,pcName:"Player 2",hp:10,curHp:7,name:"Brodude Two",playerClass:"Fighter",level:1,background:"Soldier",race:"Gnome",Alignment:"",exp:700,inspiration:0,proficiencyBonus:0}];

ko.applyBindings(new App(initialData));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>Players</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: players">
  <li>
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <h4 data-bind="text: healthWarning"></h4>
    <input disabled type="range" min="0" data-bind="value: curHp, attr: { max: hp }">
    <input type="number" min="-10" max="10" data-bind="value: subtractValue">
    <button data-bind="click: addHp">update HP</button>
    <span data-bind="text: hpPercentage() + '%'"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm gonna give you accepted answer because that does do what I asked for, but I came to a different solution. What I decided to do in the end was, when copying over the json properties manually, i made maxhp and curhp observables then and there based on `pc.curHp` and`pc.hp` like so: `obCurHp: ko.observable(pc.curHp)`. I then just made functions that calculated the percentage and the progress bar width (bootstrap) using said observables. This way, if the observables ever change, the dependencies change too, and thus everything gets cascade updated. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: I feel like that's basically what I tried to explain. E.g., in my code example I write: `this.curHp = ko.observable(playerData.curHp);`. Anyway, glad you figured it out!